# limit or audit the use of an interface

Tags: c#

I have 3 assemblies:

- A defines an interface
- B references A and uses that interface
- C also references A

how can I make sure C does not use that interface?

splitting assemblies - not an option.

Comment: Make that Interface internal and B a friend assembly of A.

Comment: there is a class or a property that should not be used in the UI layer but must be used in the data access layer.

Comment: Is it possible that A is doing too much? Have you considered making a D and pulling out the portion that C needs from A into D?

Comment: Write your own static checker or FXCop rule? :-P

Comment: @rob - that is one of the options we were considering...

Comment: Why is C referencing A in the first place? When its not for the interface then split the assembly accordingly along the line of wished visibility and only refernce the assembly actually needed.

Answer (score 6):

You *could* make the interface internal, and use [`InternalsVisibleToAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx) to allow `B` access to the internal members of `A` (by adding the attribute to `A`). It's very coarse-grained though - you can't do it for individual members; it's all or nothing.

In general though, this sort of specific limitation just isn't part of the design of access control within .NET or C#.

Of course you could try splitting out the interface into a new assembly, and make *that* available to both A and B via `InternalsVisibleTo` - but you wouldn't want to do this too often. The platform isn't designed for this sort of thing. (It'll work, but it'll get harder to work with the more types you do this to.)

Comment: that works only for whole assemblies, I need to only limit one interface.

Comment: @ZdravkoDanev: As I say in the answer, you can't do that.

Comment: @RahulTripathi: "friend assembly" *is* InternalsVisibleTo - and it won't help with private types (which would already have to be nested types).

Comment: Put the Interface in its own assembly?

Comment: @Ralf: Had just added that to the answer :) Not something I'd want to do very often though.

Answer (score 1):

I'd place the interface in its own assembly (.csproj) and make only project B reference that assembly.

This way way you achieve, in my opinion, the best encapsulation while adhering to best practices.

Answer (score 0):

If **A** is in your control, have the class that implements your interface examine the call stack and prevent access. It's a heavy runtime hack. *I* certainly wouldn't want to use it!

If **C** is not signed, you could use some assembly rewriting magic to rewrite (copy) **A** into **A'** but without exposing the interface. Then reference **A'**. This one's a bit heavy handed too.

While I know splitting assemblies is not an option, I'm putting this for completeness: refactor them and don't reference the assembly with your interface from **C**.